# Change how [DataType.Currency] renders html

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations, currency

Currently, when applying the DataAnnotation Currency to a property, it then using DisplayFor renders this as the html :

cshtml:

```
<div>@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Price)</div>
```

html:

```
<div>$U 4.193,99</div>
```

How can I change it so the currency symbol is not `white-spaced`? 
I know I can apply a css to the div for white-space:nowrap; but it would be better if I can just change the currency string format to get :

```
<div>$U&nbsp;4.139,99</div>
```

Comment: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html

Comment: @SLaks what's the default cshtml code inside a currency.cshtml so I can extend it ? I don't know where it gets the currency symbol.

Comment: `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom display format (instead of the "Currency" attribute):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "$U&nbsp;{0:#,###0.00}")]
```

Example: http://rextester.com/PQSV4120 (Note that the "nbsp;" text is removed when the example code saves. You can manually put it back in though, and re-run it.)

**EDIT**: Changed format string and added example.

Comment: this does the same as using currency. did you actually read my question ?

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer. I originally intended to just point out that you can use a custom format string.

Comment: GREAT! 2 gems here... the use of DataFormatString AND http://rextester.com/PQSV4120 thanks!

Comment: I just figured it out the currency symbol are used in the string while this won't work with localization :(

Comment: @Bart Sorry, if localization is a requirement, then I'm not sure of the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this annotation:
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]